Is it feasible to glue coarse edge of a piece of low density particle board to the laminated face of another?
I want to build a low cost box which won't be influenced by much force. I want to glue  coarse edge of a particle board to the laminated surface of another like below:

I want to form a 30x25x15 (cm) box for indoor use with this glue technique which doesn't need to be that strong but must stand the test of time. Is it doable? What type of glue do I need? Do I need any surface preparation? Thanks in advance.
Edit: maximum 1kg object will be put and removed frequently from the box, that's why I thought simple glue without any fasteners will be enough.

Welcome to Woodworking! Before attempts to Answer this I think we need a few more details, the 1st being do you literally mean glueing to the face i.e. directly onto the laminate surface? Or did you mean it more euphemistically? Now assuming you didn't mean directly to the laminate surface, it opens up all the various possibilities for combinations of glue and joinery, or any one of the established fastener options (as seen in everything made from chipboard, from Ikea on up). If you are open to those options you need to investigate them for yourself first, then ask a Question here IF needed.

Hi thank you, I literally meant gluing to the laminated face. I've added an edit to the question. Can I get away with only gluing without any fastener if I used mdf or plywood or solid wood?

Thank you for the added detail. "Can I get away with only gluing without any fastener if I used mdf or plywood or solid wood?" In theory, yes. But if you want this more formally Answered it should be asked as a separate Q; there would be numerous important details — surface prep, quality of material (both vary, plywood especially) and last but by no means least, which adhesive you went with. Now that aside, in this case also it would be advisable to reinforce in some way.

While the planned load is small here, glueing directly to the surface is problematical. The literal surface, whether it's a more conventional lacquer or melamine, will by its nature be highly resistant to glue.
If you want to assess one aspect of how it will be if you go ahead as planned, take a scrap of your material and go ahead and put a drop of any glues you currently have on hand, ideally PVA wood glue (white or yellow) and epoxy. And why not try the tenacious superglue if you have it.
Ideally do two tests side by side with this. The first without any surface prep at all, other than making sure it's dust-free. The second area lightly scuffed up with medium/coarse abrasive, say 80-150 grit.
After a full curing period, at least a day1 see if — or perhaps how easily :-) — the drops can be removed from the surface. You may be able to just flick the PVA drop from the unprepped surface, and with more effort pick off the epoxy using only your fingernails, that's how poorly they may bond to the smooth finish.

Do I need any surface preparation?

In the suggested test above, it's a virtual certainty that you'll see better bonding onto the scuffed sample area and obviously this points you to the answer on this aspect.

What type of glue do I need?

There are multiple options as you might expect and even the least-good2, a PVA, might give you acceptable bonds for an item that seems to require little strength.
There are numerous glues that should work significantly better than any PVA wood glue but some are harder to deal with, overly expensive or too messy (IMHO). I'd suggest using epoxy here, IF you can get either a 10-min or 30-min epoxy inexpensively where you are. If you can't, I think the best option is construction adhesive. The reason for these is that they're gap-filling, which I feel is a must for bonding to the open and highly friable exposed edge of chipboard/particleboard. PVA glue is not gap-filling, hence why I say above it would be the least-good choice.
Glue alone might work, but you can easily and simply do better.
Woodworkers like to build for at least some stress, and possibly worst-case scenarios too (like dropping the completed box onto an uncarpeted floor from about waist height).
Given how easily it can be done I would highly recommend reinforcing at least minimally.
If you had a suitable nail gun3 shoot in a few along each corner; even skinny brads or finish nails will go a long way to making this so much stronger. Just a few seconds per corner, literally, and you're done.
I'd personally use bamboo skewers as dowels, specifically as through-dowels,  because they're one of my reinforcements of choice. They're small enough to be visually unobtrusive all on their own (and could be fairly closely colour-matched using touchup markers), very cheap, surprisingly strong and can be installed after the box is already assembled using no special equipment, i.e. don't require the use of any jig (so no tricky pre-drilling of aligning holes).
It seems redundant at this point, but if you wanted to go even better use larger nails. Use formal dowel joinery. Or even go whole-hog, and drill for suitable screws...... massive overkill, but had to be mentioned!

1 I'd leave it two days myself, even though every sample will seem absolutely dry and ready after only 4-6 hours (possibly even less).
2 Excluding superglue which in general would just seem an unlikely thing for you to select here for various reasons.
3 Brad nailer, finish nailer or pin nailer.

Thank you for detailed explanation of your insights. By "lightly scuffed up" do you mean removing the laminate completely and exposing the chipboard grain or do you mean to roughen the smooth laminate surface by damaging it. The terms in woodworking are still new to me so can you link an example for medium/coarse abrasive, it sounds like a sandpaper. Also drilling screws isn't overkill, I may use screws instead if I fail with glue. Nails are small thus out of sight, I may utilize, great tip.

Welcome. Sorry, scuffed up is common parlance among woodworkers so I didn't think it would need fuller explanation — it simply means to scratch the surface with the abrasive (most commonly, sandpaper). Ideally you do this fairly comprehensively, but any introduced scratches give a complex 3D surface on a microscopic level that an adhesive can physically grip to; creating what is called a mechanical bond. The same principle is used when applying fresh finish over old finish BTW, be it paint, varnish or lacquer.

Re. screws, just to be thorough I'll mention that there's generally a need to pre-drill two holes, the clearance hole (does exactly what the words say) in the first piece and the smaller-diameter pilot hole for the bulk of the screw to engage with. Also with most screws one would also want to countersink, the angled depression in the surface for the screw head to sit down into. See this old Answer for more if needed. If you want to use glue and screws.... [contd]

...you can glue first, let the glue set, then drill for the screws. This way you won't have any worries about aligning the various holes as you might if you drilled them in the respective pieces separately. If you wanted to use screws only (this is quite viable for this given the fairly small size) you'd need to get the pieces lined up well and held together well for the drilling. Generally you'd use clamps for this as you might guess, but you could in theory at least figure out something using a few books and some weight to hold things in place; not ideal, but it is doable.

I've found this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTGHJM_OHuM) which concludes that particle board is not strong enough in itself to utilize the strength of the biscuit. Miter joint exposes edge grain for both pieces which will hold the glue better than the laminated surface as well as it looks nice, I am leaning to that way. The only thing I couldn't resolve is how to make the top and bottom. Miter joint will be great for 4 sides but if I make the top and bottom 45 degree cut than all the edges would be 45 degrees which will create a sharp corner and I think it will break.

The end of the particle board will be quite weak. You could expect that even the strongest glue will pull the particles from within the "sandwich" of the laminates.
Consider to combine glue with mechanical means. The least expensive and possibly easiest method is to use dowel pins centered in the "end grain" as deeply as three to four diameters of the dowel used. Use a dowel of a diameter no more than half the thickness of the overall plank.
The portion of dowel that is to be inserted into the laminated side should have the hole drilled to no more than seventy-five percent of the thickness of the plank.
It will be necessary to construct a jig or to purchase (Item shown: US$10.00) or borrow a doweling jig to ensure good alignment accuracy.

Image above from linked Amazon site.
It is a good idea to scuff the laminated portion that is covered by the plank, to provide some "teeth" to which the glue will bond.

The Q is either going to get a major edit (which may or may not rule this A out as a viable fix for the OP) or will be closed due to insufficient detail. But either way this is worth a +1 for all the various good details.

Thank you for the great tip. I'm trying to make the manufacturing as easy as possible while keeping the cost low.  Can I get away with only gluing without any fastener (such as dowels) if I used mdf or plywood or solid wood?

MDF will give you a bit better bonding with glue only, but even that is risky. The glue joint can easily be stronger than the material being bonded. I've intentionally busted apart MDF constructions and it is consistently fracturing in the wood. One can see the weak glue segments as "clean" areas of the bond. Plywood would be slightly better as the grain will give strength to alternate plys.

As my research continues I've realized I've overestimated the difficulty of dowels, thank you for the universally useful tip, but for chipboard they might be useless. I've found this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTGHJM_OHuM) which concludes that particle board is not strong enough in itself to utilise the strength of the biscut. Probably same case for dowels.
